# Trying to get 5 V using MT3608 (step-up boost) but without success

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, ground, step-up

I designed a circuit to generate 5 V using a 3.7 V battery and an [MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf). The main problem is that I can't get 5 V but just 3.5-3.9 V, even after changing resistors.

I tried everything:

- Changing R1 and R2
- Adding another ground connecting R2 and the GND of the MT3608
- Changing the capacitor

I used the formula to get resistances and my final number is 8.5 (Vout = Vref*(1+(R1/R2)) assuming Vref is 0.6 V). I used 750 kΩ for R1 and 100 kΩ for R2. I think the schematic is fine, and that the problem is in the PCB layout. Could you help me?

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB]

Comment: Don't look at values of R3 and R9 on schematic. Values are 750Kohm R3 and 100Khom R9

Comment: Is the diode in the right way?

Comment: What are you using for a load? What's its resistance value?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Diode is in right way and Values are 750Kohm R3 and 100Khom R9

Comment: As an example, look at the suggested layout for this similar part from TI: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61099.pdf?ts=1705616642716&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253Dtps61099%2526nr%253D307

Comment: And why the skew?

Comment: Is  pin 2 ground grounded in some manner?also these circuits look correct Dash measure the feedback divider values to ensure you have not made a mistake

Comment: Hello, the skew is because the pcb is skew. The pin 2 is grounded on the bottom side above the chip. I think is too far from the loop. Can i add a jumper to fix this? Do you have any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout is exceptionally bad, particularly for such a high frequency (1.2MHz) SMPS chip.

The two loops (switch open and close) must be small area. The parts C4, C3 and L2 should be much closer to the chip and (in particular) the ground conductors should be very short. The capacitors should be connected to the ground plane very near the chip, not to some trace running away somewhere else on the board.

Always read and implement the suggestions such as "Layout Consideration" in the datasheet, and implement something very close to the recommended layout if one is provided (it is not in this case, but you might be able to find a similar chip where one is provided).

Here is a diagram showing the large loop areas in your layout, and the mystery part ‘?’ is outside this snippet. Your goal is to minimize the loop areas. Green loop is when the switch is ‘on’, blue when it is ‘off’. As well as affecting operation the loop areas affect EMI. The ‘?’ is the worst here, if the grounds were connected more directly with a jumper it might work, but would be unnecessarily noisy.

[image]

As well as making the loops small, it would also be better to have the two loops on top of each other as much as possible, so avoid the unnecessary branch shown to the right in green above and take that trace right from the D1 pad.

Comment: From L2 to the chip is 5mm. Same for C4. Do i need to put them closer?
I will put everything better. Thank you

Comment: They can be closer without crowding things too much.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful and detailed.